# Android WebView stuck zoomed in after update

Tags: android, android-webview

We have an app that is using Android WebView, but after the update to v99 or v100 it shows the web page content zoomed in. Restarting the phone after the update will fix the issue, but only temporarily. After a while it will show zoomed in webpage again.

Has anyone encountered this problem, did we do something wrong? Do we need to add some config to work after the update?

What unites the affected users at the moment is:

- Webview v99 or v100
- Android 12
- Samsung

**Update:**

Reported to Chrome as a bug bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305579 bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305201 bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305501

**Workaround:**

Web app
[image]
Android web view settings
[image]

**Update:**

Now Samsung made a fix. After the fix, the workaround above does not work anymore, while the zoom out issue is still present. If anyone has a workaround, please share.

Comment: Seems to be an issue pixel density then. When I add the <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" /> to the manifest, it looks ok, but breaks on other places. Deprecated feature as well.

Looking at window.devicePixelRatio shows changes from 1 (before the update, ok) to 3 (after the update, broken).

Trying to limit the scale with `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0" />` doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

Changing the width to 320 instead of device-width seems to fix it for the single device type.

Comment: Reported to Chrome as a bug

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305579
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305201
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305501

Comment: we are running into the same issue. So frustrating :(. It seems like this only happens on samsung devices.

Comment: @MichalKuklis See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305201, it is already assigned, but no fix yet. There are several workarounds described in comments 9, 52, and others, that seem to solve the issue if you need it.

Comment: First time im so happy that someone else has the same bug haha. Thanks for reporting and making the question.