# Ads stretching in samsung (android 12)

Tags: android, android-12, google-ad-manager

Since april this year my app is not displaying correctly the advertisements.

It happens only in samsung devices, with android 12. It's not a problem with any particular ad, even the example ad from admanager ("/6499/example/banner") is stretched (see images below).

After some research, i found the culprit in the "game optimization service" of samsung (~game booster).
My app is identified as a game by the gos, so it "optimizes" the webview that shows this ad.
It seems to be related to this post: [Android WebView stuck zoomed in after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71406345/android-webview-stuck-zoomed-in-after-update)
The previous question points to this chromium issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1305201, but none of the solutions work in my case. I cannot control neither the webview nor the content. As suggested there, installing the "game plugins" i can disable the game booster, and then i see the right image.
I read https://developer.android.com/games/gamemode/gamemode-interventions, with no success. None of those optimizations appears to affect what samsung does. (Exception: adb shell cmd game downscale 0.6 <PACKAGE_NAME> fixes it in my phone).

I run out of ideas. Did someone come across this issue? Is there any workaround? Is there a way to opt-out from this optimizations from samsung? Should it be fixed by me, google admanager or samsung?

**Graphical explanation of what i mean by "stretched"**:

It should be seen this way: [image: normal example banner]
but it is seen this other way: [image: stretched example banner]